# What makes a home/building prone to bugs?

Tags: walls, insulation, leak

What makes a home/building prone to bugs? Is it the type of walls used? Leaks in wiring and AC? Leaks in windows and doors? What does the age of the building have to do with it?

Edit: I'm interested in what makes a particular *building* prone to bugs, independent of things like food, geography, surroundings.

Related: What would you look for in choosing an apartment if you want to avoid encountering bugs?

Comment: Moisture = Bugs

Comment: We shouldn't be answering questions in comments.  So let me ask for clarification:  Wouldn't you think that food would be the main attraction?

Comment: @SDsolar I'm interested in what makes a particular _building_ prone to bugs, independent of things like food, geography, surroundings.

Comment: Are you asking theoretically about any/all bugs in general, or a specific variety of bug in a specific environment.  The former is probably too broad a question because there are endless factors.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am asking about bugs in general. I assume there's a lot of overlap in what makes a building susceptible to this bug vs. that bug. If there isn't a lot of overlap and the question is too broad, let's say we're talking about common ones like spiders and roaches.

Comment: Some are attracted to food, moisture, light, or warmth, or follow the electromagnetic field around power lines, or simply stumble upon openings.  Depending on their habitat, they may enter along the ground or through ground-level openings, build mud tunnels up an exterior wall to an opening, climb or fly into higher openings, borough through wood siding, enter the attic via openings near the roof.  If you live in a wooded area, or locations with certain types of insects, it is almost impossible to hermetically seal a house against certain ones, you need chemical treatments.

Comment: So it seems that with wood, they can get through it, but with other material, it's a matter of whether or not there are openings. Are there other materials they can get through? Are certain materials more prone to developing openings than others? Is the age of a building strongly correlated with the amount of openings that develop, or is it more a matter of how it was built in the first place? Also, it seems that when you're higher up, you're a lot less likely to encounter bugs. Is that true, or do they enter on the group and make their way up to higher levels frequently?